# Visual Studio build started at message reports time in US AM/PM. How do I get it into 24 hour clock format?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2022, regional-settings

Just migrated to Visual Studio 2022 and at the end of the build I'm seeing this:

```
========== Build started at 4:04 PM and took 04.869 seconds ==========
```

I've not seen this message in Visual Studio 2019, so I'm assuming it's new to Visual Studio 2022.

Since my regional settings are for a 24 hour clock I was expecting it to be

```
========== Build started at 16:04 and took 04.869 seconds ==========
```

Anyone here know if it's possible to change and how?

Comment: Good catch. If you use _Help | Send Feedback | Report a problem_ you can file a feedback ticket that will get to the relevant team at Microsoft. If you link it here, I'll make sure it's routed correctly internally.

Comment: @DrewNoakes I've tried to report this issue as you requested. Tried twice in Firefox (failed saying I had to logout / login in VS - Didn't help). Tried using Edge but failed to login with Websocket timeout. Any ideas?

Comment: @DrewNoakes Managed to report it, had to switch to using my personal account, not the work account. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Build-started-at-time/10338796

Comment: Thanks @sixeyes. I've forwarded it to the appropriate team internally. VS still runs on .NET Framework and I don't know of a standard time format string that would do what we want here.

Comment: Surely "t" or "T" would do the time. And for the date / time I saw in the ticket "g" or "G" would do?

Comment: You're right. One of my colleagues pointed that out too. The bug's with the right people now. Feel free to ping me about it here in future if needed.